# JSONPath / QML - Get Elements in String Arrays

Tags: json, qml, jsonpath

So I'm using a JSONListModel for QML, and I need help parsing this [JSON File](http://minecraft-api.com/v1/players/?server=darkcrest.cf.gs)

It's a Minecraft Server Query which gets Online Players' names. However, I'm having trouble adding each node to my List delegate.

This is my code:

```
ListView {
    JSON.JSONListModel {
        source: "http://minecraft-api.com/v1/players/?server=darkcrest.cf.gs"
        query: "$['players'][*]"
        id: playerNames
    }

    anchors.top: players.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: units.gu(1)

    model: playerNames.model

    delegate: Item {
        Text {
            text: model
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I have a query, which is the JSONPath to the element I want to view.

What I want to get is the players' names, one after the other. I used a wildcard to get all of the names, but when I set the Text's text to model ("$['players'][0-x]") I get:

```
file:///home/brendan/UTouch-Apps/ServerStatus/JSONListModel/JSONListModel.qml:15:32: QML ListModel: append: value is not an object
```

Which points to the line:

```
property ListModel model : ListModel { id: jsonModel }
```

In JSONListModel.qml.

So yeah, I'm guessing my path is wrong. I don't know how to handle arrays such as the ones in the JSON file in the link.

If the file were something like:

```
{
    players: [
         "name": "Whatever1234",
         "name": "Person987"
    ]
}
```

I could just do

```
text: model.name
```

But I can't because the nodes don't have a name. They are just values.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually from looking at the [JSONListModel](https://github.com/kromain/qml-utils/tree/master/JSONListModel), [ListModel::append](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-listmodel.html#append-method), along with the JSON you're parsing the issue is with the `append` as reported which is at [line 40 in JSONListModel.qml](https://github.com/kromain/qml-utils/blob/master/JSONListModel/JSONListModel.qml#L40)

```
jsonModel.append( jo );
```

In this case `jsonModel` is a `ListModel` therefore `append` requires `jo` to be JSON dictionary, i.e.

```
myListModel.append( {"cost": 5.95, "name":"Pizza"} )
```

Your query is valid and does return the array the problem is the inner elements are not in the valid form for a `ListModel`.

There are two options:

1. Request/Change the source JSON data to conform to name/value encoding or,
2. Request/Fix JSONListModel to provide the value as an anonymous name or string.

All that said, for #2 it looks like this has already been [reported in JSONListModel](https://github.com/kromain/qml-utils/issues/1) and is currently unresolved.

Hopefully that answers your question and at least provides you with some options going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll look into both options and try to solve my problem. Thanks so much!